# Find Probability Of First Rolling an even number and then rolling a

Tags: probability

The sides of a cube show numbers $2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4$. Alice is rolling this cube three
times. Find the probability that the first roll results in an even number, and the sum
of the numbers obtained from the second and third rolls is six.

My Work: $\frac46\times\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$

$\frac46$ = $4$ even numbers / $6$ possible outcomes

$3$ = Amount of Successful Outcomes when rolling a die twice ($2 + 4 = 6$ is one, $4 + 2 = 6$ is another, and $3 + 3$ is the third)

$6^2 = 36$ possible outcomes/arrangements when rolling a die twice.

so
$\frac{3}{36}$

$\frac46\times\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $4$ faces out of $6$ have an even number, so you are correct on the first roll being even having probability $\frac46$.

Your analysis about the second and third rolls having a sum of $6$ is not correct.

One way is to roll a $2$, then roll a $4$. This has probability $\frac16\times\frac36=\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{12}$

Another is to roll a $4$, then roll a $2$. This has probability $\frac36\times\frac16=\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{12}$

Finally, you can roll a $3$, followed by another $3$. This has probability $\frac26\times\frac26=\frac{4}{36}=\frac{1}{9}$

The overall probability of rolls $2$ and $3$ having a sum of $6$ is the sum of those probabilities.
$\frac{3}{36}+\frac{3}{36}+\frac{4}{36}=\frac{10}{36}=\frac{5}{18}$

To answer your question, multiply the probability of first roll even by the probability of the second and third rolls having sum of $6$

$\frac46\times\frac{5}{18}=\frac{20}{108}=\frac{5}{27}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\frac {4}{6}$ is the probability of getting even number in the first throw.

Also as you have mentioned, you can get sum of six from the next two throws as $4+2$, $2+4$ and $3+3$. But in a throw, probability of getting a $4$ is $\frac {3}{6}$, of getting a $3$ is $\frac {2}{6}$ and of getting a $2$ is $\frac {1}{6}$.

So the probability of getting a sum of six from next two throws = $2.\frac {3}{6}.\frac {1}{6} + \frac {2}{6}.\frac {2}{6} = \frac {5}{18}$

Now you can multiply by $\frac {4}{6}$.